# save eclilpse preference settings across all the workspaces

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preferences

I am customising eclipse. I have to save eclipse preference settings across all the workspaces.
I know manually we can export and import the preference settings from a file.
But I need to do it programmatically.

I can capture preference change events using `IPreferenceChangeListener`.
But I need to know how does export and import functionality works at lower end. How will the imported `.epf` file will make changes in the actual preference settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IPreferencesService` service provides preference export and import services via its `exportPreferences` and `importPreferences` methods.

For example:

```java
OutputStream os = ....

IPreferencesService service = Platform.getPreferencesService();
IEclipsePreferences node = service.getRootNode();

service.exportPreferences(node, os, null);
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think not all preferences are being captured by this. That's the reason why there is the Oomph project dealing with this issue.

Comment: Thanks greg, it actually worked. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes pimpf0r, it doesnt captures all the preferences.

Comment: When I'm trying to import the exported file using `service.importPreferences(InputStream);` then the eclipse just hangs and i need to kill it. It doesn't even throws any error log. How to resolve this.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea. I don't use this feature, you will need to do some debugging.